# how to Print a list of unique icons used on article title and how many times was it used

Tags: selenium-webdriver

http://slashdot.org/
Print how many articles are on the page, since it is dynamically changed everyday. 
Print a list of unique icons used on articles.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

hi find the answer below

```
public class latestNews {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("https://slashdot.org/");
        // take everything inside the list for article 
        List<WebElement> latestNews =  driver.findElements(By.className("story"));
        // take everything for icon inside the list 
        List<WebElement> releventicons =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='topic']/a/img"));
        // print total number of latest articles for today 
        System.out.println("Total article for today is : " + latestNews.size());

        // also plz note that size of icons will also be same as articles
        // print headings and icons of the total number of articles for today
        for(int i =0;i<latestNews.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Article for today is : "+ latestNews.get(i).getText() + "=="+ releventicons.get(i).getAttribute("alt"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: hi m glad it helped you please mark it as your answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
 List<WebElement> totalarticale = driver.findElements(By
        .cssSelector(" #firehoselist>article"));

System.out.println("size is "+totalarticale.size());
```

article icon number is same as articale number.

Comment: Cool, it print out all the details. Only thing different is By.name ("story") printout the title only